# Does GWT is help in speed, if i make some widgets into single common GWT module?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

I am running an application with **GWT** and Google App-engine using *Java*. I have some common widgets that are "*MultiSuggestBoxWidget*", "*TextBoxWithHelpTextWidget*", "*DateBoxWithHelpTextWidget*" etc.

I have them in separate files and in separate packages. These widgets I am using in many modules in my application. ***Is there any advantage if I make all these widgets into single GWT common module.*** I am thinking that it may help in efficient processing speed.

Which means it will not generate *JavaScript* code many times if I make all widgets into single GWT module.

If anybody having experience on this.

Answer (score 0):

It offers no optimization. GWT COMPILER is fantastically smart to exclude any unused code from widgets, packages or util classes. You can derive more benefits using other gwt features at screen level.  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting

You can also try optimizing widgets at different levels

1) precompiling associated css and i18n strings-

```
a) https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle
b) http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource
```

2) Also please use [Chromes Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) to study network resource usage and memory profiling for your screens to get better view of what to tune.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. The GWT compiler takes all sources in your own project and all other libraries and compiles them together as one big monolitic application. It performs numerous optimizations over the generated code. Therefor it doesn't matter were the sources are located, in different libraries or in one single library. Also any unused sources or even methods are removed.

GWT can generate reports that can give you insight into how big your classes are. See the GWT documentation on how use them and what the reports are: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport